# Encrypting a text with A-Z letters

Tags: python, encryption

What I am trying to do is make a program that encrypts a text file (which you specify) with the letters A-Z and then save that in another file.

For example, make it so that the first letter in the text file is "A", the second letter "B", and the third letter "C", etc.

I was wondering if someone could help me out, or at the very least give me some tips on how to get started.

Comment: What do you mean by encrypting ? Could you please give sample input / output ?

Comment: To get started read a python tutorial for beginners then write a `hello world` in python, then work on reading a file and saving it to a new file (i.e copying).. You need to explain your encryption method better, not sure if you mean a simple caesar-cipher.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you literally, this does it:

```
from itertools import cycle
import string

with open('input.txt', 'rt') as input, open('output.txt', 'wt') as output:
    cipher = cycle(string.uppercase)
    for line in input:
        encrypted = []
        for c in line:
            if c in string.letters:
                encrypted.append(cipher.next())
            else:
                encrypted.append(c)
        output.write(''.join(encrypted))
```

Input file:

```
This is a sentence.
And so is this.
```

Output file:

```
ABCD EF G HIJKLMNO.
PQR ST UV WXYZ.
```

The problem with this is I don't think that there a practical way to un-encrypt the text since there's a major loss of information in the process -- the encrypted version of a letter depends only on it's relative position in the file, and *not* what it was originally.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a stab at:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from itertools import count
from operator import itemgetter


text = 'hellothere'

counter = count(0)
ref = {}
for ch in text:
    if ch not in ref:
        ref[ch] = next(counter)

letters = ''.join(el[0] for el in sorted(ref.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1)))
frm, to = zip(*zip(letters, ascii_uppercase))

from string import maketrans

trans = maketrans(''.join(frm), ''.join(to))
print text.translate(trans)

# ABCCDEABFB
```